# How would I flatten a pivoted python pandas table into a de-normalized list?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wanting to flatten a pivoted Python Pandas table into a de-normalized list.

The table:
[image: pivoted pandas table]

The result I'm after (where the strings are the column values):

```
[
  [CC_Contact_Id, question_text, Form_ID, Network_ID, Question_Id, Id],
  [CC_Contact_Id, question_text, Form_ID, Network_ID, Question_Id, Id],
  [CC_Contact_Id, question_text, Form_ID, Network_ID, Question_Id, Id],
  [CC_Contact_Id, question_text, Form_ID, Network_ID, Question_Id, Id],
  [CC_Contact_Id, question_text, Form_ID, Network_ID, Question_Id, Id]
]
```

I think there are some nesting issues since I did

```
pivot_table = unified_df.pivot_table(rows=['CC_Contact_Id','Question','Question_Answer'])
```

I'v tried

```
pivot_table.values.tolist()
```

but I get

```
0:[676.0, 10.0, 954.0, 375001.0]
1:[676.0, 10.0, 735.0, 374996.0]
2:[676.0, 10.0, 740.0, 375016.0]
3:[676.0, 10.0, 746.0, 375046.0]
4:[676.0, 10.0, 743.0, 375041.0]
5:[701.0, 10.0, 987.0, 475142.0]
6:[676.0, 10.0, 955.0, 375051.0]
7:[701.0, 10.0, 854.0, 475077.0]
8:[676.0, 10.0, 741.0, 375021.0]
9:[676.0, 10.0, 741.0, 375031.0]
10:[676.0, 10.0, 741.0, 375026.0]
11:[676.0, 10.0, 741.0, 375036.0]
12:[676.0, 10.0, 738.0, 375006.0]
```

And I'm missing the CC_contact_id (the index), Question and Question_Answer that it was pivoted on.

What is the best way to flatten the Panda's table into a denormalized list?
Where every row has the CC_Contact_Id, Question, and Question_Answer fields values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CC_Contact_Id, Question and Question_Answer are all in the index, so to get them out and then put them in the lists you can do:

```
pivot_table.values.reset_index().values.tolist()
```

Comment: Error - extra ".values" 
Correction: 
pivot_table.reset_index().values.tolist()

and that worked